# Modern board games are still based on the idea

Tags: questions

**Early board games represented battles between two armies and, modern board games ---- on the idea of beating the opposing players.**

A)still base 
B)are still based

What would you answer this? I thought that the answer B was obvious but it came up to be A.

Comment: I don't think "still base" (A) produces a grammatically sound sentence in your example - at least, not in BrE or AmE. Try asking your teacher to justify answer 'A', then let us know what they said.

Comment: I don't get the comma placement in "and, modern." If your "came up to be A" came from the same source, that source is not reliable. "Still base" is missing something.

Comment: @Lawrence: Playing devil's advocate: if I used "modern board games still base themselves on ..." would that not be considered correct? While technically, a board game does not design itself, I've seen similar use cases where it seems at least accepted if not grammatically correct.

Comment: @Flater "still base themselves" is grammatically sound, even if people quibble about metonymy or other figures of speech.

Comment: The comma after "and" doesn't seem correct to me. Are you sure it is in the original question? If so, I wouldn't particularly trust the source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Early board games represented battles between two armies and, modern board games ... on the idea of beating the opposing players

1. still base
2. are still based

Your teacher is wrong. Only the second answer is correct.

However, there is a third option:

3. still base **themselves**

This answer is also correct (and uses the same tense as the first answer, which may have been the main focus of the question). Maybe your teacher forgot to add "themselves" to the answer.

But that still does not make the second option wrong! It is still correct (and I think the most commonly expected way to phrase it).

But if you had to pick from the existing options, **only the second one is correct**.